# How do you access the DataTemplate generated content of a databound ContentControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Let's say I have the following:

```
<FrameworkElement.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodel:MainViewModel}">
        <view:MainBaseView />
    </DataTemplate>
</FrameworkElement.Resources>

<ContentControl x:Name="uxMaster" Grid.Row="0" Content="{Binding}" />
<view:AddRemoveBaseView x:Name="uxButtons" Grid.Row="1"
      DataContext="{Binding ElementName=uxMaster, Path=Content.uxGrid}" />
```

Now let's say that the `Content` is binding to a new instance of a `MainViewModel`. Through the magic of WPF `DataTemplates`, it will create an instance of the `UserControl` `MainBaseView` where the `ContentControl` is and set its `DataContext` to the `Binding`.

Question is, how the heck do you access this generated content (i.e. the `MainBaseView` instance)? I'm trying to bind uxButtons' `DataContext` to a grid inside of the generated `Content`, but upon inspecting the `Content` it only contains the binding and not the `MainBaseView` instance and its logical/visual tree.

Comment: What do you mean with "contains the xaml"? Do you want the actual markup text as the result of the binding, or do you want the `uxGrid` property of the content of uxMaster?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean xaml... I meant the element tree containing the uxGrid. In other words, where is the MainBaseView instance so that I can walk its logical and visual tree and bind to it if I want?

Comment: If the xaml is as you have provided it, couldn't you just type `{Binding uxGrid}`?

Comment: No. If {Binding} binds to an instance of MainViewModel, then {Binding uxGrid} obviously won't work. MainViewModel has no uxGrid property, but the DataTemplate generated MainBaseView does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
/// <summary>
/// Get the first child of type T in the visual tree.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
/// <returns>the first child of type T in the visual tree, or null if no such element exists</returns>
public static T GetChildOfType<T>(this DependencyObject source) where T : DependencyObject
{
    for (var i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(source); i++)
    {
        var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(source, i);
        if (child != null && child.GetType() == typeof(T))
            return child as T;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(source); i++)
    {
        var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(source, i);
        var t = child.GetChildOfType<T>();
        if (t != null) return t;
    }

    return null;
}
```

then you simply call

```
var baseView = uxMaster.GetChildOfType<MainBaseView>()
```

Comment: This is the answer of course; I was hoping someone would also show if it's possible in pure xaml (this method required the use of a converter).